# mongodb: sum of difference between two fields

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate

I am trying to build a query returning the difference between 2 fields. 
Here are the documents of my collection:

```
[
 { _id: 1, type: 'in', amount: 10 },
 { _id: 2, type: 'in', amount: 5 },
 { _id: 3, type: 'out', amount: 7}
]
```

I am trying to get the `balance`: total of 'in' amount minus 'out' amount.
The output should be something like:

```
{ ..., total: 8 } ( (10 + 5) - 7 )
```

This is what I have tried to do:

```
db.aggregate([
 {
   $group: {
     _id: '$type',
     total: { $sum: '$amount' } 
   }
 }
])
```

This just output the total per type:
in --> 15,
out --> 7

How do I in a later stage find the difference of the above result?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`$group` with an `_id` of `null` and use `$cond` to make the value either positive or negative. Specifically, if type is not `in`, then you can use `$multiply` to multiply the `$total` by `-1`. Something like the following should work:

```
db.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$type',
      total: { $sum: '$amount' } 
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: { $cond: {
        if: { $eq: [ '$_id', 'in']},
        then: '$total',
        else: { $multipy: [ '$total', -1 ]}
      }}}
    }
  }
])
```